# Navigate to totally new page on button click using react js_having no route buttons on next page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-navigation

I have been trying to **navigate** from one page to another using **Route/BrowserHistory** but what they do is that the router buttons stay on the top of the page. However, I want to navigate to a totally different page which does not contain that routing buttons.

For example in my case, my first page consists of two buttons **Configuration** and **User Portal**. On clicking any of the buttons, I want to jump to a new page i.e. UserPortal page on clicking **User Portal**.

Here is my code:

```
<div className="App">
   <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
          <ol className="breadcrumb" style={{background: 'none'}}>
             <div className="breadcrumb-item">
                <Link to="configuration">
                  <button className='btn btn-primary' id='config' >Configuration</button>
                </Link>
             </div>
             <div className="breadcrumb-item">
                <Link to="userPortal">
                  <button className='btn btn-primary' id='portal' >User Portal</button>
                </Link>
             </div>
          </ol>
        </nav>
        <Switch>
           <Route path="/configuration" component={ArduinoInterface} />
           <Route path="/userPortal" component={UserPortal} />
        </Switch>
     </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
</div>
```

What should I do to get the desired result?

Your help would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: you want the buttons to be in the configuration page only ?

Comment: No. I want buttons on the main page/ first page only. Configuration and User portal are two different pages on which I want to navigate on button click.

Comment: your links are missing a `/`, example `<Link to="configuration">` => `<Link to="/configuration">`

Comment: > I want to navigate to a totally different page which does not contain that routing buttons  

I don't get this part

Comment: @KainatAltaf checkout **react portals**. That might be the topic you are looking for.

Comment: @h1b9b Tried '/' too. [link] (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) In this example, when you click Home button, the div below the router buttons changed to "Home". On clicking About, it changes to "About". Routing buttons stay on top in this case. I want to move to next page let say Homepage, which does not consist of routing buttons(Home, About ,Dashboard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem. I followed [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-navigation-mk5lb?from-embed) and it worked.

Index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(<Router history={history}>
    <Routes />
  </Router> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Routes.js

```
<Switch>
     <Route path="/" exact component={MainPage} />
     <Route path="/configuration" component={ArduinoInterface} />
     <Route path="/userportal" component={UserPortal} />
     <Route component={MainPage} />
</Switch>
```

MainPage.js

```
<div>
    <button type="button" id='config'><Link to='/configuration'>Configuration</Link></button>
</div>
<div >
    <button type="button" id='portal'><Link to='/userportal'>User Portal</Link></button>
</div>
```